# Prioritize / Ignore CSS rules when working with external css files (kendo ui and bootstrap)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Can't modify those CSS files. Not that I would want to anyway if they were local files.

```
<button type="submit" data-role="button" class="button-right btn-success km-widget km-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign km-text"></span>&nbsp;Ok</button>

kendo.mobile.all.min.css:9
.km-flat .km-button {
  ...
}

bootstrap.min.css:7
.btn-success{
  ...
}
```

I understand that because the kendo file has more specific selectors, it'll take those rules.
I would like to just completely ignore rules for .km-button (which is added by using data-role="button" on my button), **so it uses bootstrap's rules instead of kendo's**.

I could remove the class name dynamically using jQuery, but i'm wondering if it can be done some other way.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just overwrite the class with !important?

Comment: Removing the class seems legit. You could also use CSS `!important` to overwrite the kendo styles. Or use inline styling for `data-role="button"` using jQuery's `.css()`.

Comment: @Banana No, because what I want to do is use bootstrap's rules rather than kendo's (that might've not been clear in my post, i'll edit it), even though kendo's are more specific. I'm not gonna start modifying kendo's css files as it will not be maintainable in the future.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/using-kendo-with-twitter-bootstrap) may be all you need to do. It looks like the Telerik folks thought of this before and just made Kendo to work out of the box with Bootstrap using a different css file. They even went to the trouble of creating a [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bootstrap/) for it. Granted there is little to say about Kendo UI mobile but its at the very least worth a shot.

Comment: I did see that topic but I am not sure that it is meant for Kendo mobile. I tried it out and as soon as I removed kendo.mobile.all.min.css, my elements were all messed up :(